# Show div based on Radio Button (with POST)

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, radio-button

I know there are lots of similar questions, but I haven't been able to find something that does exactly what I have in mind. I have a radio button on the first page (and other content) and a submit button that posts some data to another page. On this second page, I have 2 divs and I want to show div1 if option1 was selected on the first page, div2 if option2 was selected. Seems straightforward, but I'm having trouble. Could someone please help me? Here is my code:

Page 1

```
<form method=post action='page2.php'>
  <input type="radio" id="option1" value="option1" name="options">
  <input type="radio" id="option2" value="option2" name="options">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Page 2

```
<?php $options = $_POST['options']; ?>
<div id="Div1" style="display: none"></div>
<div id="Div2" style="display: none"></div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
 if ($options == 'option1') {
  document.getElementById(Div1).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(Div2).style.display = "none";
 }
 else if ($options == 'option1') {
  document.getElementById(Div2).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(Div1).style.display = "none";
 }
 return false;
});
```

Comment: "having trouble" what trouble?

Comment: You have a server/client boundary between "Page 2" and "JS" in your example. $options listed in "Page 2" is in no way related to $options in "JS".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `php echo` is one way of passing your PHP variable down to the client side javascript:

```
<?php $options = $_POST['options']; ?>
<div id="Div1" style="display: none"></div>
<div id="Div2" style="display: none"></div>
<script>
  $(function() {
   var $options = "<?php echo $options ?>"
   if ($options == 'option1') {
    document.getElementById(Div1).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById(Div2).style.display = "none";
   }
   else if ($options == 'option1') {
    document.getElementById(Div2).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById(Div1).style.display = "none";
   }
   return false;
  });
</script>
```

Alternatively you could eliminate the javascript entirely and user server side logic to render only the required div:

```
<?php $options = $_POST['options'];
    if ($options == "option1"){
        echo "<div id='Div1'></div>"; 
    } else {
        echo "<div id='Div2'></div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I realised I had made a "rookie mistake": I had another page with a radio button that showed different divs dynamically on click and I just re-used the same code without thinking that I actually didn't need javascript this time because it's not dynamic, but it's a submitted form! Thank you so much!